# Memory Allocation With Pointer to Pointer to Void

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management, void-pointers

Let's assume that I have a struct with a void ** member. This member serves as an array of pointers to data channels. The data type is irrelevant. Below is an example of how I'd like to allocate memory for this 2D array and then associate channel pointers with their memory.

```
#define N_CHANNELS (/*Number of data channels*/)
#define N_SAMPLES (/*Number of data samples per channel*/)
typedef /*Some data type*/ DATA_TYPE;

void **ppdata; /*Conceptual struct member*/

/*Allocate memory for array of data channels */
ppdata = (void **) malloc(sizeof(DATA_TYPE *) * N_CHANNELS);
ppdata[0] = malloc(sizeof(DATA_TYPE) * N_CHANNELS * N_SAMPLES);

/*Cast for pointer arithmetic and data access*/
DATA_TYPE **ptr = (DATA_TYPE **) ppdata;

/*Associate channels with their memory*/
int alloc_index;
for (alloc_index = 0; alloc_index < N_CHANNELS; alloc_index++)
{
     ptr[alloc_index] = (*ptr + alloc_index * N_SAMPLES);
}
```

So, the question arises: Is this dereference and allocation behaving as I have assumed it is?

```
ppdata[0] = malloc(sizeof(DATA_TYPE) * N_CHANNELS * N_SAMPLES);
```

i.e., is this allocation compatible with the manner in which I later access the memory?

```
DATA_TYPE **ptr = (DATA_TYPE **) ppdata;
...
ptr[alloc_index] = (*ptr + alloc_index * N_SAMPLES);
```

Comment: @4386427 I've allocated the memory for all channels w/ that second malloc() statement because I need the data for all channels to be in contiguous memory. I assign ppdata[1], ..., ppdata[N_CHANNELS -1] with their appropriate addresses in the for loop.

Comment: `typedef  DATA_TYPE;` is `typedef int DATA_TYPE;` This is determined at compile time.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY The typedef is just for the purpose of illustration. In an application of this idea the data type would be delivered another way.

Comment: Although `void *` is the "generic" pointer type in C, it turns out that `void **` can *not* portably be used as a generic pointer-to-pointer.  So your line `DATA_TYPE **ptr = (DATA_TYPE **)ppdata` is suspect.  See http://c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html

Comment: @4386427 The purpose of the loop is to initialize, not dereference.

Comment: @sgoldburg The allocation isn't compatible with the intended use. You need to allocate the array of DATA_TYPE first, then the ppData array separately with size `sizeof (void*) * N_CHANNELS`, and then set the ppdata items to the first byte of each DATA_TYPE, respectively.

Comment: @4386427 If I'm not mistaken, sizeof(DATA_TYPE) is implicit in the pointer arithmetic because ptr is (DATA_TYPE **)

Comment: @sgoldburg - ah yes, I think I see what you are trying to do. I'm not really sure why you want to do it like this. Seems much more complicated than a real 2D array or an array of pointers to individually `malloc`ed areas.

Comment: It appears that what you are doing is creating a 1D array of pointers to 1D arrays of data.  In your first array, you are allocating a 2D array's worth of space.  You are then iterating through the elements of the 1D array of pointers to arrays and setting the pointers to point to the different rows of the 2D array you allocated in the first element of the array of pointers.

Does that accurately describe what you are attempting to accomplish?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Yes.

Comment: It looks like it might technically work, but I'm going to echo the sentiments of @4386427 and wonder why you're going about it this way.  `malloc`ing an array of pointers to point to the different rows seems rather unnecessary since you can already access the different rows as-is without an additional pointer dereference to get there.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons In the case of void **ppdata, I don't believe that sort of access is possible without the initialization I have outlined above. Can you explain what you mean by "you can already access the different rows as-is without an additional pointer dereference"?

Comment: Assuming you do need your matrix to be `malloc`ed onto the heap, you allocate memory to your matrix: `DATA_TYPE *pdata = malloc(sizeof(DATA_TYPE) * N_CHANNELS * N_SAMPLES);`

Then to access the `i`th row, you access `pdata[i*N_SAMPLES]`.  It's not quite as pretty-looking as `ppdata[i][]`, but at least you don't have to malloc an extra array of pointers and then dereference them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your general idea looks OK to me, but `(void **) malloc(sizeof(DATA_TYPE *) * N_CHANNELS)` makes my spider-sense tingle. You allocate space for an array of `N_CHANNELS` pointers to `DATA_TYPE`, but treat it as an array of pointers to `void`. There's nothing in C that guarantees that a `void *` and a `DATA_TYPE *` have the same size and representation (unless `DATA_TYPE` happens to be `char`). So your subsequent assignment to `ppdata[0] = ...` might produce garbage when looked at as the bits of a `DATA_TYPE *` (which is what you do later through `ptr`).

I'd much prefer it this way:

```
/* overflow check omitted */
DATA_TYPE *storage = malloc(N_CHANNELS * N_SAMPLES * sizeof *storage);
/* error check omitted */

/* overflow check omitted */
DATA_TYPE **pointers = malloc(N_CHANNELS * sizeof *pointers);
/* error check omitted */

for (size_t i = 0; i < N_CHANNELS; i++) {
    pointers[i] = storage + i * N_SAMPLES;
}

/* struct member */
void *pdata = pointers;
```

Then later on you can recover your array of pointers by doing:

```
DATA_TYPE **pointers = pdata;
do_stuff_with(pointers[i][j]);
```

---

Technically you don't need a separate array of pointers, because you have a nice rectangular array. You could just do:

```
/* overflow check omitted */
DATA_TYPE *storage = malloc(N_CHANNELS * N_SAMPLES * sizeof *storage);
/* error check omitted */

/* struct member */
void *pdata = storage;
```

And later on:

```
DATA_TYPE *storage = pdata;
do_stuff_with(storage[i * N_SAMPLES + j]);
```

I.e. just manually calculate the index from `i` and `j`.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense and confirms my suspicions.

Answer (score 0):

C does not support the ability to discover datatype at runtime.  You are going to have to pass in a variable that defines the number of bytes of the datatype you are going to be using if you want this to work with generic datatypes.

Comment: The question is about the allocation. DATA_TYPE is just for illustration.

Comment: The issue I'm having is that your code just cannot work as you have written it.  So when asking about the correctness of a line of code that includes `sizeof(DATA_TYPE)`, that code will be inherently incorrect.  And when you are casting to `DATA_TYPE`, this is again, something that just cannot work.  If these are things you are aware of but write the code this way anyway for 'illustration', it makes it difficult for answerers having to figure out which parts of the code are intentionally incorrect and which may be possible flaws with what you are actually attempting.

Comment: I've edited the question for clarity. If you can provide an answer regarding the stated question on allocation I would appreciate it.